Mobile manipulator with MoveIt
I am working on a mobile-manipulator having a robotic arm and a mobile base. The mobile base is a 4 wheel holonomic drive(mecanum wheels) robot.
I am trying to use MoveIt for controlling the arm and nav2 for controlling the base. I doing am it this way because i was not able to find a way to controll both the arm and mobile base using moveit. I did find one here but it is of no help as it is not demonstrating the MoveIt setup assistant process also it is using differential drive base.
My question is how do I integrate both Nav2 and MoveIt to work together? Shall I add virtual joint between the arm and mobile base(fixed joint) or the joint between the mobile base and the world(planar)?
Additional Questions:

Is there any way to do both the things(planing for arm and mobile base) using MoveIt?
Would it be good idea to directly code arm and mobile base movemet(path planing + Trajectory Generation + costraint checking + path execution) in C++ instead of using MoveIt?

I am thinking to directly code the motion planing logic on c++ because of 2 reasons:

I dont feel like learning anything when using movit as most of thing are Black Box. To understand its working I need to go through its huge codebase(i have tried this as well).
I dont feel there is good support for mobile manipulators in MoveIt. Although its the best when it comes to robotic arm.

